# Trying to find and replace text in an IFS file using CLOB files

Tags: ibm-midrange, clob, rpgle, ibm-ifs

I'm trying to find and replace text in a given IFS file. I have used the same code before for replacing lines in this config file. However, we are adding a new config option, so I'm automating the turning on and off of it.

The code below executes and returns and sqlcod of 0 when doing the 'exec SQL set', but nothing in the file gets changed. I'm not sure if it doesn't like the spaces in the text I'm replacing or what. Any help is appreciated.

```
//----------
    //Variables
    //----------
    dcl-s toF SQLTYPE(CLOB_File);
    dcl-s frmF SQLTYPE(CLOB_File);
    dcl-s clcmd varchar(2024);
    dcl-s path char(512);
    dcl-s sslTxt char(15) ccsid(37);

    //-----------------
    // Data Structures
    //-----------------
    //DCL-DS PGMSDS   PSDS       Qualified;
    //    MsgTxt        Char(80)   Pos(91);
    //End-Ds;

    //----------
    //Constants
    //----------
    dcl-c lower const('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    dcl-c upper const('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

    //-----------
    //Prototypes
    //-----------
    ///include sndmsg;

    dcl-pr runcmd extpgm('QCMDEXC');
        *n char(2024) options(*varsize) const;
        *n packed(15:5) const;
    end-pr;

    dcl-pi *n;
       sys char(3);
       par char(3);
       ssl char(1) ccsid(37);
    end-pi;

    //------
    // Main
    //------
    Exec SQL   Set Option  Commit=*None, DatFmt=*ISO, TimFmt=*ISO,
                          Naming=*SYS,  CloSQLCsr=*EndActGrp;
    exsr cPath;
    exsr mkBak;
    exsr chgF;
    exsr chown;
    exsr endpgm;

    //---------------
    //Construct path
    //---------------
    begsr cPath;
        path = '/LANSA_' + %xlate(upper:lower:sys) +
               'pgmlib/x_lansa/x_' + %xlate(lower:upper:par) +
               '/execute/SD1_FRAMEWORK_ENG_VLFONE_Definition.DAT';
    endsr;

    //------------------
    //Make copy of file
    //------------------
    begsr mkBak;
        clcmd = 'CPY OBJ('''+ %trim(path) +''') ' +
                'TOOBJ('''+ %trim(path) + '.bak' +''') ' +
                'REPLACE(*YES) ' +
                'OWNER(*KEEP) ';

        runcmd(%trim(clcmd): %len(%trim(clcmd)));

        clear clcmd;
    endsr;

    //----------
    //Edit File
    //----------
    begsr chgF;
        monitor;
        frmF_Name = %trim(path) + '.bak';
        frmF_NL = %len(%trim(frmF_Name));
        frmF_FO = SQFRD;

        toF_Name = %trim(path);
        toF_NL = %len(%trim(toF_Name));
        toF_FO = SQFOVR;

        if ssl = 'N';
            sslTxt = 'P   239 1 FALSE';
        endif;


            exec SQL Set :toF = replace(:frmF,
                               'P   239 1 TRUE', :sslTxt);


        on-error;

        endmon;
    endsr;

    //------------------
    //Change File Owner
    //------------------
    begsr chown;

        clcmd = 'chgown obj(''' + %trim(path) + ''')' +
               ' newown(QOTHPRDOWN)';
        //runcmd(%trim(clcmd): %len(%trim(clcmd)));
        clear clcmd;

        clcmd = 'chgown obj(''' + %trim(path) + '.bak' + ''')' +
               ' newown(QOTHPRDOWN)';
       //runcmd(%trim(clcmd): %len(%trim(clcmd)));
        clear clcmd;

    endsr;

    //-------------
    // End Program
    //-------------
    begsr endpgm;
       *inlr = *on;
       return;
    endsr;
```

Comment: SQL doesn't work that way...

Comment: Work what way? I have this code working with other text strings. It just won't work for this particular string.

Comment: Ok, interesting...I've never tried to use SQL for this.   I guess it could work.  But you mention "adding a new config option" and "automating the turning on and off of it."  Your code only turns it off if it's turned on.   Does the file already have the flag in it and set to on?

Comment: what do you see when you debug the program?  Place a breakpoint after the SQL REPLACE function runs.  Make sure the return value is what is expected.

Comment: How do you know what SQLCODE is being returned? I don't see where the program is looking at it?

Comment: What does the data in the file look like? Are you sure you have the right number of spaces in the search constant?

Comment: I was able to see the SQLCODE in debug. In debug I also verified that the number of spaces is correct. And I verified that :sslTxt is what I'm expecting it to be. Again, I use this same code with other values in this file. I have to wonder if the spaces in this one are throwing it off as that seems to be the only thing that's different. To anyone saying I should do this in another language better suited, I'd love to. I have several Python scripts that could do the job. Problem is, this has to be portable for customer sites. Not all of our customers have Python on their iSeries.